# What is X-FC-Nonce Header [PHP]

Tags: php, api

i trying to use api and i write this code and my output is

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":"MISSING_PARAMETER",
        "message":"Missing X-FC-NonceHeader"
     },
    "request_id":"a7c6305b96eb4c999a95c4a5ef87b5d9",
    "status":"ERROR"
}
```

What is F-FC-Nonce how to fix it

```
$headers = array("Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$path = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://iai.flashsoftapi.com/v1/thai-id-card-ocr');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERPWD,'key:key');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $base64);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$text = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

echo $text;

Comment: They apparently want a nonce. You'll need to contact them to find out what they expect.

Comment: There's obviously a [documentation](https://flashsoft.ai/en/doc/api-doc) and you can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [their documentation](https://flashsoft.ai/en/doc/api-doc), they generate a nonce using the following Python code:

```
def generate_nonce(length=16): 
    """Generate pseudorandom number.""" 
    return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)])
```

So from the looks of it, a nonce can be made in PHP using this method

```
function generate_nonce($length)
{
    $out = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i)
        $out[] = rand(0,9);
    return implode('', $out);
}
```